# How to build mono repo across languages or cross platform?

Tags: build, azure-devops, cross-platform, monorepo

> Blockquote

let's assume i have mono repo in that repo i have different independent projects (**java,nodejs,c++)

so whenever i do a changes on particular project that one only i should build can we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Say your monorepo is organised this way:

```
/
 README.md
 ...
 aCppPrj/
         README.md
         build/
         doc/
         src/
         ...
 aJavaPrj/
          ...
 aNodePrj/
          ...
 common/
```

In this example the common directory has some scripts shared by all projects and changes there should queue a build as well.

The build for the C++ project must have a similar trigger

```yaml
- trigger:
    paths:
      include:
        - 'aCppPrj'
        - 'common'
      exclude:
        - '*'
```

note the quotes to avoid the YAML parser going mad.
You include the folders that must trigger your build and exclude everything else.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema#triggers) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git#ci-triggers) for details.